# Image loading issue in BXslider

Tags: php, bxslider

I am using BX slider to load my thumbnails on home page, when i am loading images using static li like below

then slider working fine and display all images, but when i am using php loop like below to load images dynamically then images does not load

```
<?PHP $query = "SELECT * FROM gb_books";$result = mysql_query($query);?>
       <div id="main" role="main">
      <section class="slider"> 
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
             <?php 
          while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
          ?> 
             <li><img src="http://globeveda.com/admin/img/books/<?php echo $array['tch_book_image']; ?>" /></li>
            <?php } ?>  
            </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @DannyG Same Issue here. Is it fixed?

Comment: No, i changed the slider